# How to count the duplicate times of duplicate lines in Vim?

Tags: vim

Now I am working on Windows with Gvim. I want a pure Vim way without using the external command of the operating system, to count the duplicate times of duplicate lines in Vim.
In other words, I want a pure Vim way working like ":!sort % | uniq -c".

Comment: In case it's useful to you, apparently you can use windows powershell commands in the same way you would the unix shell commands (and I guess windows has an equivalent of sort and uniq): https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/26463/how-to-run-external-commands-in-vim-from-windows-os

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no ready-made equivalent. Below is a quick and dirty approximation.

Doing:

```
:echo getline(1,'$')->map({ idx, val -> getline(1,'$')->count(val) .. ' ' .. val })->sort()->uniq()->join("\n")
```

on this buffer:

```
foo
foo
bar
baz
```

echoes this:

```
1 bar
1 baz
2 foo
```

in the command-line, which should provide a good starting point.

Breakdown:

```
:echo {expr}
```

echoes the output of `{expr}` in the command-line.

```
getline(1,'$')
```

returns a list with every line in the buffer.

```
->map({ idx, val -> getline(1,'$')->count(val) .. ' ' .. val })
```

prepends each item of the list with its count in the list.

```
->sort()
```

sorts the list.

```
->uniq()
```

removes duplicate items from the list.

```
->join("\n")
```

and finally joins it with newline as separator so that it looks good when echoed to the command-line.

Comment: Perfect answer! Thx a lot!@romainl

Comment: Hmm, @Armali's is *much* better.

Comment: But yours is a one-liner. :-)

Comment: Yours is much faster especially when it comes to file with tens of thousands lines.@Armali

Answer (score 5):

While romainl's implementation is  perfectly correct, using a [dictionary](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#Dictionary) to count the occurrences may have a better time complexity.

```
:let dict={}
:g/$/let ln=getline(".") | if !has_key(dict, ln) | let dict[ln]=0 | endif | let dict[ln]+=1
:for [k, v] in items(dict) | echo v." ".k | endfor
```

Comment: "may have a better time complexity" is quite the understatement: mine runs in seconds while yours runs in hundredth of seconds. Nice.